# Pandas New Column from Conditions Across Multiple Columns

Tags: pandas, feature-engineering

This is stumping me with pandas.. I have a data frame with 5.8M rows and a date index. I 5 columns A, B, C, D & E and would simply like to create a new column F_Score based on simple math below:

```
F_Score=0
if A > = B:
    F_Score = 1.0 
else:
    F_Score= -1.0

if B > = C:
    F_Score = F_Score + 1.0 
else:
    F_Score = F_Score - 1.0

if C > = D: 
    F_Score = F_Score + 1.0 
else:
    F_Score = F_Score-1.0

if D > = E:
    F_Score = F_Score + 1.0 
else:
    F_Score = F_Score -1.0
```

I cannot seem to find a simple way to do this. Any suggestions?

I tried turning all of the columns into numpy arrays and then doing a for loop storing the result into a new array and then creating a column F for the dataframe. This seems very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, use `np.select`.  if you create some mock data, SO will give you a good verifiable solution. Or even nested `np.where`.

Answer (score 3):

```py
np.sum(-np.sign(np.diff(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)), axis=1)
```

From the if chains, it seems like if we take the column-wise successive differences and look at their sign:

- if sign is positive, subtract 1
- if sign is negative, add 1
  (note that the difference is taken from right to left).

So we go to the NumPy domain, take the column-wise difference, get the signs, negate them, and their summation is the desired F_score here.

pandas supports `diff` too, but since the problem is label-agnostic and you mentioned you have *a lot* of rows, going to NumPy domain should make it faster, and hopefully fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your math in a function and apply it with apply: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

should look something like that:

```
def logic(a,b,c,d,e):
    do something...
    return f

df["f"] = df.apply(lambda row: logic(row["a"], row["b"], row["c"], row["d"], row["e"]), axis=1)
```